# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, weird exception location in thread with anonymous function

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015, socketexception

When using threads with an anonymous function that had an exception, visual studio shows string initialization.

[image]

Is this intended behavior such that it tracks ip to its initialization?

Running in release mode x64 bitness, optimizations enabled and unsafe compiling is selected. It is a simple winforms window.

Comment: Are you running in Release mode or otherwise have JIT optimisations enabled?

Comment: Release mode x64. Optimizations enabled.

Comment: That's your problem. In Release mode with optimisations the JIT will remove and rearrange code so that the PDB file becomes almost useless. Rerun your code in Debug mode.

Comment: That solved. Thank you.